# Is opcache_reset supposed to work on windows?

Tags: php, opcache

Enviroment wamp on windows, PHP version 7.4

The result of `opcache_get_status` after calling `opcode_reset` shows
opcache_enabled => false
restart_pending => 1

This goes on for a long time and no actual restart is happening, and the manual restart count still shows 0.

Is this a specific windows gotcha thing, or I should look for some misconfiguration (where?)

Answer (score 0):

I set up a WSL2 enviroment on the same machine and `opcache_reset` behaves as expected, so it must be just another way in which php behaves differently on linux and windows.